# Using a range pattern how does one detect EOF within the range?

Tags: awk, gawk

I want to detect the case: In which I do **not** find the end of my range. Given this `awk` command:

```
 awk '/^START/,/^STOP/ { print $1,$2 }'  x.dat
```

and this data:

```
garb
START d1
stuff d2
STOP d3
garb
START d1
```

How can I detect that the **second** START isn't followed by a **STOP**? The reason for this is error detection. I'd like to "signal" some kind of error when this is detected.

Comment: Please mention what is the expected output in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use range expressions as they make trivial tasks very slightly briefer but then anything more interesting requires duplicate conditions or a complete rewrite. Instead of:

```
awk '/^START/,/^STOP/ { print $1,$2 }' x.dat
```

you should have written:

```
awk '/^START/{f=1} f{ print $1,$2 } /^STOP/{f=0}' x.dat
```

and then your new requirement might just require:

```
awk '/^START/{f=1} f{ print $1,$2 } /^STOP/{f=0} END{if (f) print "The sky is falling!"}' x.dat
```

Without more details and specific sample input/output to test against, that's the best I can do....

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do.  You could look at the output and see if the last line matches 'STOP'.  If you want to detect it within `awk`, you could do something like:

```
awk '/^START/,/^STOP/ { print $1,$2; a=1 } /^STOP/{a=0} 
    END{ if(a) { 
      # condition detected
     }}'
```

But it's not really clear what you want to do.

Comment: it's for error detection. If I don't see the STOP something bad has happened.